# Printing asterisk based on Int array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a loop that will create lines of asterisks, with the amount of asterisks on a single line equal to the INT array. This loop will start at index 0 until the end of the array. Having trouble figuring out how to code this. Any help is appreciated. This is what I've come up with so far and I'm stuck on what to do next.

```
int e = 0;
int[] yValuesInt = new int[yValues.length];
    for (z=0; z<yValues.length; z++)
    {
        yValuesInt[z] = (int) yValues[z]; // changing from double array to int
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<=arrayAmount-1; i++) // loop to continue until array is over
    {

    while (e<yValuesInt[z]) // loop that is creating asterisks based on int array
        {
            System.out.print("" + asterisk);
            e++;
        }
        System.out.println(": "  );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my own code, because I don't know what your `z` variable is or the `arrayAmount` variable etc.

This concept is really simple, however, and I have a small example below:

```
static int[] intArray = {5, 6, 10, 4};

public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){ // Iterate through the int array
            for(int j = 0; j < intArray[i]; j++){ // loop intArray[i] times
                System.out.print("" + "*");
            }
            System.out.println(": "  );
        }
    }
```

Gives the following output:

```
*****: 
******: 
**********: 
****:
```